# Where to find simple skeleton for ejb 2.x project with ant build file?

Tags: ant, jakarta-ee, ejb

Where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

All the following are using xdoclet -  a sensible way to build ejb 2 apps:

- http://www.ericsson.com/developer/sub/open/technologies/open_development_tips/docs/odt_xdoclet_test
- http://www.liuzehua.com/xdoclet_tutorial/
- http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/01/30/xdoclet.html

ALl of them are articles which you can download the source code.

Comment: I was hoping to find something similar to maven's archetype:generate

Comment: Sorry. Your best chance is perhaps Appfuse 1.x - http://raibledesigns.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=AppFuse, but I couldn't find any ejb reference there